# Create class diagram from c++ source?

Tags: c++, class-design

Is there any free tools available for generating class diagram from c++ source files and if possible for mfc source files too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) support

Answer (score 1):

You could try SourceNavigator. I'm not sure what the current state of the project is, but [here's a place to start](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Excellent suggestion. The new project can be found at http://sourcenav.berlios.de/ ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/) (a KDE-based app).  It allows you to import code to create a model, that can then be used to generate UML diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Umbrello is probably fine for projects with a limited number of classes, and certainly requires manual intervention for tuning. I imagine doxygen/graphviz is more suitable for larger projects.